# Finding BLUE of $\theta$ where $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ have common pdf $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\theta}e^{-|x|/\theta}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ have the common pdf $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\theta}\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{\theta}\right)$$, where $x$ can be any real number and $\theta$ is positive.

I’m trying to construct the best linear unbiased estimator (BLUE) for $\theta$, and to do so, I first found $E[X^2]$, since $\theta$ is a scale parameter. After some calculus, I arrive at $E[X^2]=2\theta^2$. Now, because I want an unbiased estimator for $\theta$, I need to change the argument of $E[.]$ so that the expected value equals $\theta$.

How do I do this? The expectation operator is linear, and I don’t know how to get rid of the square.

Comment: Why do you need your estimator to be linear and what exactly do you mean by that? Linear in the observations $X_i$? In this case, your estimator would need to have the form $\sum w_i x_i$ (to be linear in $X_i)$ in which case its expected value would always be zero. You may be more lucky trying to construct an estimator that is linear in $|X_i|$, if that is an option.

Comment: Oh good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, you said that squaring x isn’t linear, but the absolute value isn’t linear either..

Comment: Yes. The absolute value isn't linear in $X_i$ either. I tried to reason that an estimator that is linear in $X_i$ is not very helpful as for zero mean $X_i$, it will always have mean zero as well. You'll need some nonlinearity.

Comment: But the question specifically asks for the BLUE. How should I make sense of this?

Comment: Then there are two options: (a) it's a trick question as any estimator that is linear in the $X_i$ has mean 0 and hence no linear unbiased estimator for $\theta$ exists or (b) we are misunderstanding the question. I would think that (b) is much more likely than (a) but you're the one with the question in front of you...

Comment: Yes it’s b. Apparently blue is defined in my book as a linear combination of unbiased statistics that have identical variance and are pairwise independent, so using the absolute value works.

Comment: Here $E(X_i)=0$, but $E(|X_i|)=\theta$ for each $i$.\\ So consider a linear estimator in $|X_i|$'s, namely $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\sum a_i|X_i|$ such that $E(T)=\theta$. This implies $\sum a_i=1$.\\ Now find $\operatorname{Var}(T)$ and minimize it wrt the $a_i$'s subject to the constraint $\sum a_i=1$. This would give you the optimal $\hat a_i$'s for which variance of $T$ is minimized.\\ So your BLUE would be $\sum \hat a_i|X_i|$.